# Removing event listeners before closing a module

Tags: apache-flex

I add an instance of this module to the dispay list and then remove it.
Will the event listener attached to foo create a leak?
A simplified module:

```
<s:Module creationComplete="init()">
    <fx:Script>
        protected var foo:Bar = new Bar();
        protected function init() {
          foo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, foo_clickHandler);
        }

        protected function foo_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
            //do something
        }
    </fx:Script>
</s:Module>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This module **does not have memory leaks** since you add listener to a local object, not to a `Stage`, `StyleManager` or some other global-accessible stuff.

Comment: I found this [presentation](http://blogs.adobe.com/aharui/GarbageCollection/GCAtomic.ppt) very helpful. Looks like memory leaks are caused by adding listeners to 'special' objects on top of the object tree that will always be referenced and will never be garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

It will. You should remove the listener, or use weak references when creating the listener.

```
foo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, foo_clickHandler, false, 0, true);
```

Comment: When is the right time to remove events? Which event should I listen to? Maybe removedFromStage? This memory leak stuff is quite confusing :/

Comment: The easiest solution is to use the weak reference, so that as long as something else in the application has a handle to the Bar, it wont be garbage collected. The more explicit way to remove it would be to use either the removed or removedFromStage events.